# Why is only one Django template block working?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm learning Django and JS and jQuery all at the same time for a project I'm working on, and I'm having trouble with running JavaScript in a Django template block OTHER THAN {% block content %}.

I've seen several tutorials use a {% block javascript %} template block for JavaScript, but I can only get my JavaScript to run if I include it in the {% block content %} block of the html file.  If I include it in a  like I've seen in the tutorials, it doesn't work (and neither do other functionalities, like html tags).

Here's my base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    {% block style %}
    {% endblock style %}
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock javascript %}

</body>

</html>
```

This works:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="med_input_form">
        <div class="form-group" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="{{form.input_meds.id_for_label}}">{{form.input_meds.label}}</label>
            {{form.input_meds}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reconcile Meds</button> 
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul id="med_output">
    </ul>
</div>
<p>test</p>


<script>
     console.log('MedInput page loaded');
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

but this doesn't:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}


<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="med_input_form">
        <div class="form-group" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="{{form.input_meds.id_for_label}}">{{form.input_meds.label}}</label>
            {{form.input_meds}}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reconcile Meds</button> 
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul id="med_output">
    </ul>
</div>
<p>test</p>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
     console.log('MedInput page loaded');
</script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?  Is there something I need to do to enable this feature?

Thanks!

**Update** I changed the javascript code to just console.log to make sure it wasn't anything else, and it's the same.  It works if it's part of the content block, but not the javascript block.

It also doesn't seem to matter what I change the name of the block to (extra_js, scripts, etc), it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check the frontend with your browser developer tools to see if the JavaScript is in there.

Comment: @niklas  If I include the JavaScript in the {% block content %}, it shows up in the HTML elements.  If I include it in the {% block javascript %} it doesn't.

Comment: As far as i can see in the doc, the correct syntax for for `endblock` does not have parameters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#templates try removing them

Comment: @niklas  Thanks for helping me with this, but it looks like that doesn't work either.  Looks like an `endblock` parameter is allowed, and it works for the `{% block content %} {% endblock content %}`  It's so frustrating that one block works and the other doesn't!

Comment: try a different block name, try to rearange your imports and stick to the demo tutorial. if it still does not work. i will look closer.

Comment: @niklas I tried different block names, different import order and different content (I tried HTML only) and none of that works.